# How to generate an svg file in node.js (data visualisation using rough.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg

The html code below is a minimal example to create an svg element displaying a simple rough.js polygon generated from an array of data. I want to use the js code in a nodejs program that generates the same svg and saves it to a file. What would be the simplest way of achieving this?

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/roughjs@latest/bundled/rough.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
    var rc = rough.svg(svg);
    var data = [[40, 20], [140, 30], [100, 130]];
    svg.appendChild(rc.polygon(data));
    document.body.appendChild(svg);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Answering my own question here)

The solution I found uses `xmldom` (from [this github issue](https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode/issues/149#issuecomment-300856699)):

```js
// file generate-rough-svg.js
const { DOMImplementation, XMLSerializer } = require('xmldom');
const xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
const document = new DOMImplementation().createDocument('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'html', null);
const rough = require('roughjs');
const svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
const rc = rough.svg(svg);
var data = [[40, 20], [140, 30], [100, 130]]
svg.appendChild(rc.polygon(data))
let xml = xmlSerializer.serializeToString(svg);
console.log(xml)
```

Now I can run

```
node generate-rough-svg.js > image.svg
```

to generate the svg file.